# Can any one explain from where they taking url path to display image

Tags: lightning, component

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    
    <aura:attribute name="car" type="Object" access="public" 
                    default="{
                             'sObjectType' : 'Car__c', 
                             'Name' : 'AUDI',
                             'picture__c' : '/resource/cars/luxury/ford.jpg'}"/>
    <lightning:button variant="neutral" class="tile" >
        <div style="{# 'background-image:url(' +v.car.Picture__c + ')'}" class="innertile">
            <div class="lower-third">
                <h1 class="slds-truncate"> {!v.car.Contact__r.LastName}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning:button>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: What specifically are you asking about? The source of the URL is in the expression shown in the code above.

Comment: for example : i created a custom url filed called picture and i given some image url link copied from google so how i define that Picture__c files in the above component code
and here they defined in this way '/resource/cars/luxury/ford.jpg' 
so i was confusing and not getting the image on my application page 
so can you please explain ? below part code .
 <aura:attribute name="car" type="Object" access="public" 
default="{'sObjectType' : 'Car__c', 'Name' : 'AUDI',  'picture__c' :'/resource/cars/luxury/ford.jpg'}"/>

Comment: Who is "they"? Is this code from Trailhead? Please [edit] your post to provide clear context.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Static Resource URL. This [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/v/modules/visualforce_fundamentals/visualforce_static_resources) goes in to more detail. Basically, `/resource/<resourceName>` is the path for a file uploaded in Setup > Static Resources. This file happens to be a ZIP file ("compressed folder"), with a folder called "cars", which contains a folder called "luxury", followed by the actual file name stored in this folder ("ford.jpg"). In order to replicate this code, you also need to upload the static resource, otherwise you'd just get a 404 error on the network.

Comment: thanks for the explanation

Comment: Hi there 
im trying to get the images on UI but its not displayed on UI 
picture__c' : '/resource/cars/luxury/ford.jpg 
its not setting into Object URLfield called Picture__c 
so do i need to give the URL same as' /resource/cars/luxury/ford.jpg  ' this 
or do i leave it as empty ?